# CSS `Filter: blur()` not working properly on Safari

Tags: html, css

Started working with `filter: blur()` on a project and noticed it doesn't work that well with Safari.

Instead of the `blur` expanding outwards like it does on other browsers, on Safari it seems as if `overflow` was set to `hidden`, but that's not the case. Sometimes it works and sometimes breaks completely. I've also noticed the bug gets more "aggressive" when the filter has a transition. Anyhow, Here's a comparison versus [Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWoIb.jpg) (on Chrome) and [Not Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBqZz.jpg) (on Safari). Also, here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/Yurdesou/pen/bGrXmox?editors=1100) with a replica of this bug (it's only visible on Safari though).

As always, thanks for your help in advance. nd in case you want a preview of the code without going to the codepen, here it is:

Code:

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  background: #272727;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: black;
  font-family: Gill Sans;
}

.content-div {
  width: 30rem;
  height: 30rem;
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.title {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1rem;
  left: 1rem;
  z-index: 2;
}

.filter {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  height: 90%;
  width: 93%;
  background: red;
  /* FILTER TRANSITION */
  transition: filter .2s ease-in-out;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 1rem;
  left: 1rem;
  z-index: 1;
}


/* FILTER */

.filter:hover {
  filter: blur(3.3rem);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="content-div">

    <span class="title">Lorem Ipsum</span>

    <div class="filter">
      HOVER OVER ME
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

OBS: For some reason CSS's markdown isn't working, sorry about that.

Answer (score 16):

If anyone's wondering, below are 4 CSS rules that need to be added to the specific class. Sometimes, Safari has issues rendering hover states (e. g. combining hover scale and border radius), so this fixes most these issues.

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: This helped me out so much with my blur + animation effects on safari! Thank you

Comment: Thank you!! works on fixing an issue with blur + radial-gradient

Answer (score 10):

The highest rated answer is not the best in my opinion. There are too many properties declared there. Just this is enough:

```css
transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
```

Source:
https://graffino.com/til/raw/CjT2jrcLHP-how-to-fix-filter-blur-performance-issue-in-safari

Answer (score 7):

I just had a similar issue, but none of the solutions worked on Safari 16.1,
For me the solution was to add a:

`will-change: transform`

to the blurred element.

Hope this helps someone.

Working snippet:

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  background: #272727;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: black;
  font-family: Gill Sans;
}

.content-div {
  width: 30rem;
  height: 30rem;
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.title {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1rem;
  left: 1rem;
  z-index: 2;
}

.filter {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  height: 90%;
  width: 93%;
  background: red;
  /* FILTER TRANSITION */
  transition: filter .2s ease-in-out;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 1rem;
  left: 1rem;
  z-index: 1;
  will-change: transform;
}


/* FILTER */

.filter:hover {
  filter: blur(3.3rem);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="content-div">

    <span class="title">Lorem Ipsum</span>

    <div class="filter">
      HOVER OVER ME
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Worked for me regarding a filter:blur + gradient Z index issue

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  background: #272727;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: black;
  font-family: Gill Sans;
}
.content-div {
  width: 30rem;
  height: 30rem;
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.title {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1rem;
  left: 1rem;
  z-index: 2;
}

.filter {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  height: 90%;
  width: 93%;
  background:  red;

  /* FILTER TRANSITION */
  transition: filter .2s ease-in-out;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 1rem;
  left: 1rem;
  z-index: 1;
}

 /* FILTER */
.filter:hover {
   -webkit-filter: blur(15px);
   -moz-filter: blur(15px);
   -ms-filter: blur(15px);
    filter: blur(15px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="content-div">
    <span class="title">Lorem Ipsum</span>
    <div class="filter">
       HOVER OVER ME
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That didn't work too :c. I have a couple of ideas of how to fix this brewing in my mind right now. If any of them work I'll update the post.

Answer (score 1):

```
.filter:hover {
  -webkit-filter: blur(3.3rem);
}
```

Put `-webkit` before `filter: blur(...)`

Comment: Tried that before. Sorry, I should've said what I've tried to before. I've found a solution to this problem but currently do not have time to update the post. It basically consists of using `backdrop-filter: blur()` as a substitute. As soon as I have some time I'll update the post with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the current Safari version on Windows is some way behind the current Safari version for Mac.

On Windows, the current Safari version is only 5.1, compared with 6.0 and 7.0 on Mac.

The bad news for you is that Safari 5.1 does not support the filter style.

There is no way around this; it simply isn't supported, and won't be until Safari gets an update on Windows.

The only good news is that there aren't that many people using Safari on Windows, so this issue shouldn't affect too many of your users.

You can see more about the browser support for this feature on CanIUse.com: http://caniuse.com/#search=filter

Answer (score 0):

This'll work fine

```
.filter:hover  {
-webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(15px);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

this problem is happening because **safari 5.1 does not support the filter style**. If you have chrome you can use it but if you dont you have to download or you cannot use  filter style.

Comment: I'm on Safari 14.0.2